# Do I have to spit out this dairy?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, meat-and-milk

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12169/so-you-ate-dairy-after-meat-now-what):

[substitute "6 hours" in this question with whatever one's tradition might be]

Suppose it is less than 6 hours since Reuven last ate meat. Out of habit, he mistakenly bites into a dairy candy bar. While it's still in his mouth - but before he swallows it - his kind friend Shimon reminds Reuven that he's fleishig.

Now Reuven is in a dilemma: Does he spit out the candy bar or swallow it?

I would expect an answer treat the type of food as an example, and treat all cases (e.g. what if it was milk, etc.)

So what should Reuven do?

Comment: yydl, if your question is asking if the bracha is satisfied by tasting or chewing, you should define that in your post.

Comment: @YDK Nope. Let's assume he already made the Shehakol on some other food item (i.e. Bracha issues aside).

Answer (score 2):

Spit it out. If you're doing something prohibited, you minimize it as much as possible. If halacha says you shouldn't be eating this candy bar, then why let it linger in your mouth anymore? Spit it out! (No, you don't have to make yourself vomit.)

Comment: But perhaps once it entered your mouth you were already "over" and now it doesn't matter?

Comment: @yydl, see Sanhedrin 62 and the discussion of  מתעסק בחלבים ועריות. "if someone had something in their mouth that they weren't sure was *chelev* or *shuman* and they chose to swallow it ..." we see that swallowing constitutes further prohibited activity beyond just when it went into your mouth.

Comment: I recall the question being posed in the context of hilchos brachos, and the outcome being that one should spit out the food and accept the brachah le-vatalah.

Comment: why? bracha livatala is more chamur than a minhag to wait.

Comment: @yitznewton, perhaps you're thinking of a slightly different case: If you've *made the bracha* but not eaten any yet, better to take a bite rather than have a wasted bracha. If you've made the bracha and already tasted it, why would spitting it out ruin your bracha? (You make a bracha on chewing gum, right?)

Comment: My case was making brachah, then before swallowing, realizing it is the wrong type. R' Bodner discusses brachos on prohibited foods in Ch. 13 Par. C, but it seems like he's only dealing with issur Torah. I thus retract what I said about not eating the food; I don't know. I could hear logically that letting the brachah go le-vatalah (IIRC R' Bodner in Kezayis quotes R' C. Kanievsky that this is not necessarily d'Oraysa) may be worse than eating within x hours (which I presume is minhag).

Comment: @ArielK OP clarified in a comment above that he is assuming this is a case where `"he already made the Shehakol on some other food item (i.e. Bracha issues aside)"`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Avnei Yoshpai](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=874&st=&pgnum=70&hilite=) at the end of Anaph 5 - if you already made a Bracha and then remembered that it was still too early to eat dairy - then you should quickly clean out your mouth well and eat a little bit in order that it should not be a Bracha L'Vatala.

Answer (score 0):

פשוט. Spit it out.

In סימן צח where it discusses the דינים of קפילא, it says if one were to taste איסור שנתערב בתוך היתר he would have to spit it out. The פרי מגדים says so clearly there.

However, here there is a slight complication because there are opinions which permit you to have milk after meat provided that you were מפסיק בין סעודה לסעודה. Namely תוספות. However, the majority of ראשונים don't learn like that so one would not be able to rely on that.

So spit it out.

Comment: Can you cite where in the _PMG_ this is?

Comment: Also, wouldn't this answer apply only within the first hour, since everything after that is dependent on _minhag_?

Comment: @msh210 Why is the first hour different from the rest? Ashkenazim me'ikar hadin hold like tosfot and the rest is a chumra (albeit a highly recommended one -- see the Rama YD 89:1) so even the first hour is dependent on minhag.

Comment: If the majority of rishonim don't learn like Tos., then why does the Rema pasken like Tos?