# If one makes a bracha on something not Kosher should he eat it to avoid saying G-d's name in vain or not?

Tags: halacha, blessing, kashrut-kosher, food

If one makes a bracha on something not Kosher (meat and milk,chicken and milk, pork…) should he eat it to avoid saying G-d's name in vain or not?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64937/bracha-levatalah-vs-waiting-between-meat-and-milk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is saying a bracha over non-Kosher food a sin or does it simply not count as a Mitzvot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82845/is-saying-a-bracha-over-non-kosher-food-a-sin-or-does-it-simply-not-count-as-a-m)

Comment: @JoshK Not a dupe. This question merely presupposes that it is a sin to say a beracha on non-Kosher and asks whether, once he has said the beracha, is that lisence to eat the treif.

Comment: Is this about one making the bracha *knowing* that the food was not Kosher, or about one who, after making a bracha, finds out "oops, this isn't Kosher"?

Comment: yosef, you can't change the question anymore now that it has upvoted answers. You can ask any new questions at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 12):

He already said God's name in vain since non-kosher food doesn't warrant a blessing. Eating the food now isn't going to help that.

> אכל דבר איסור, אף על פי שאינו אסור אלא מדרבנן, אין מזמנין עליו ואין מברכין עליו לא בתחלה ולא בסוף. (שולחן ערוך או"ח סימן קצו:א)‏
>   If one ate something prohibited, even if it was only prohibited rabbinically, one does not combine him to a zimmun, nor would he say a beginning or after blessing [on that food]. (Shulchan Aruch OC 196:1)

After such a mishap [one should say ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16398/759).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87031/discussion-on-answer-by-double-aa-if-one-makes-a-bracha-on-something-not-kosher).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (in Laws of Blessing 6:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en),<sup>1</sup> in the event of saying a *Bracha l’vatalah* (an unrequired blessing), the fix is to say, “Baruch Shem kavod Malchuto l’olam va’ed.”

> **צְרִיכִים לִזָּהֵר שֶׁלֹּא לְבָרֵךְ חַס וְשָׁלוֹם בְּרָכָה לְבַטָּלָה, אוֹ לִגְרֹם לְעַצְמוֹ לְבָרֵךְ בְּרָכָה שֶׁאֵינָהּ צְרִיכָה.** וְאִם נִכְשַׁל וּבֵרַךְ בְּרָכָה לְבַטָּלָה, וְכֵן בְּעִנְיַן אַחֵר אִם נִכְשַׁל וְהוֹצִיא שֵׁם שָׁמַיִם לְבַטָּלָה, **יֹאמַר אַחֲרֶיהָ, בָּרוּךְ שֵׁם כְּבוֹד מַלְכוּתוֹ לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד.‏** ...‏

One should not consume the non-kosher food. There are a variety of reasons for the various prohibitions against eating all the different types of non-kosher food. Many are enumerated in the [Mishnah Torah, Laws of Forbidden Foods.](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Foods.1?lang=bi) For the various types and reasons, see there.

---

<sup>1. See also [10:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.10.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and the sources cited there, particularly the Pri Megadim, for more details.</sup>